# Java Process Stops Suddenly

Tags: 12.04, java, process

This is something I couldn't find a solution at all and quite weird. I have Java process that is started by Openbox. This has been working for about an year and now after some unspecified time Java process suddenly stops with no errors.

I don't see any JVM crash report nor any `OutOfMemoryError` in logs even if I enabled `+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` on JVM. I also have monitored Java process through JConsole and found no memory issues. So I believe that this is something to do with Ubuntu process fiddling Java process.

When I invoke Java with strace

```
futex(0xb6964ba8, FUTEX_WAIT, 2542, NULL <unfinished ... exit status 143>
```

is the message I got. I found following questions relevant

[First Quest](http://bytes.com/topic/unix/answers/928417-java-dies-unexpectedly-cents) 
[Second Quest](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Jenkins-JVM-crashes-after-few-minutes-after-start-td4417465.html)

My device is running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. Java version 1.6.0_26 Sun HotSpot server VM. I found no errors or messages in syslog and kernel.log. One more thing is I recently installed sar utility and is configured to run every 10 minutes. I am suspecting whether this has an impact on that. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved after I removed sysstat utility but I couldn't justify why it happened so.